# Can I expect (require) failure for a go test?

Tags: unit-testing, go

In other test frameworks that I have used, when writing test helpers, it's nice to be able to automatically test them, i.e. test that they fail as well as pass.

Let me use the following for the helper (in reality it's a lot more complex):

```
func IsRedirect(t *testing.T, code int) {
    assert.True(t, code >= 300)
    assert.True(t, code < 400)
}
```

Then sure, I can write:

```
func TestIsRedirect(t *testing.T) {
    IsRedirect(t, http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

But I'd also like to write something like:

```
func TestNotRedirect(t *testing.T) {
    t.RequireFailure()
    IsRedirect(t, http.StatusOK)
}
```

Note, I don't really want to write:

```
func IsRedirect(code int) bool
```

because the function has more than just one or two conditions that can fail, and I want to be able to `assert` on the specific failure case.

Comment: IMO test frameworks that have "assume failure" modes are dumb. What does failure mean? That one of the conditions you test failed? That all of them failed? That you got a random nil pointer dereference? That your initialization code crashed? If you expect any of those things to happen then you can test for them. It's trivial to reverse your conditionals. It's impossible to make a framework guess correctly what you actually mean.

Comment: That seems like a really strange implementation. You're in control of the assert.True calls; you're telling the framework what is "correct" and "incorrect", and then you want to invert the meaning of correct and incorrect? Just assert what you actually expect.

Comment: "Negative" testing is important. The goal is to test that known bad input (from the user, whatever) fails as expected. "The test case failed successfully, as expected."

Comment: @Art This question doesn't present a good use case for "expect failure" tests. The point of expecting failure is that you write the test against the _desired_ behavior, but if there's a bug or you haven't finished the implementation yet, you can have your test runs record the current status of the behavior without causing CI to fail.

Comment: Did everyone above read that I'm attempting to test a "test helper", that would be used by actual tests (that should normally pass).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
func IsRedirect(t *testing.T, code int, b bool) {
    assert.Equal(t, b, code >= 300)
    assert.Equal(t, b, code < 400)
}

func TestNotRedirect(t *testing.T) {
    IsRedirect(t, http.StatusOK, false)
}
```